# Создание шаблона окна в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

В WinForms можно было сделать окно с элементами. Потом создать еще одно окно, унаследованное от первого и добавить на него еще элементы. Как в WPF делает такое? Что-то у меня не выходит такое провернуть.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Это можно сделать, но довольно сложно, и требует известной технической квалификации.

Давайте рассмотрим пример, где нужно сделать окно с дополнительным текстовым сообщением снизу.

Для начала, вам нужно унаследоваться от класса `Window`:

```
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_MessageCountHost", Type = typeof(Panel))] // будет объяснено позже
class WindowWithMessage : Window
{
```

и определить переопределение метаданных, чтобы стили, определённые в `ResourceDictionary` без ключа, подхватывались:

```
    static WindowWithMessage()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
                typeof(WindowWithMessage),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(WindowWithMessage)));
    }
```

Затем, вам нужен сам текст как свойство окна:

```
    #region dp string MessageText
    public string MessageText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MessageTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MessageTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageTextProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "MessageText",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(WindowWithMessage),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(OnMessageChanged));
    #endregion
```

При изменении `MessageText` будет вызываться `OnMessageChanged`.

В принципе, нам не особенно нужно знать, где именно будет показываться — это, в конце-концов, вопрос стиля/темплейта. Но предположим, что нам нужна кастомная логика: мы хотим считать, сколько раз message менялся.

```
    int messageCount = 0;

    static void OnMessageChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        WindowWithMessage self = (WindowWithMessage)d;
        self.messageCount++;
        self.UpdateMessageCount();
    }
```

Для этого нам нужно знать, где это отображать. Для этого нам нужно попросить темплейты, чтобы они сообщали нам нужную информацию. Для этого используем объявление `TemplatePart` перед классом (см. выше).

```
    Panel messageCountHost;
```

Визуальный элемент для счётчика сообщений может меняться только при применении темплейта.

```
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        messageCountHost = GetTemplateChild("PART_MessageCountHost") as Panel;
        UpdateMessageCount();
    }

    void UpdateButtons()
    {
        if (messageCountHost == null)
            return;

        messageCountHost.Children.Clear();

        var textControl = new TextBlock()
        {
            Text = messageCount.ToString()
        };

        messageCountHost.Children.Add(textControl);
    }

}
```

Окей, это был lookless control. Теперь для него нужно написать визуальную часть.

Для этого вы должны в корне своего проекта создать подкаталог Themes, и в нём `ResourceDictionary` `Generic.xaml`. Названия важны, не меняйте их. Если такой файл уже есть, просто добавьте в него стиль.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type code:WindowWithMessage}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type code:WindowWithMessage}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <AdornerDecorator>
                        <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0"
                                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MessageText}"/>
                                <Panel x:Name="PART_MessageCountHost"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </AdornerDecorator>
                    <ResizeGrip x:Name="WindowResizeGrip"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                Visibility="Collapsed" IsTabStop="false" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResizeWithGrip">
                        <Setter TargetName="WindowResizeGrip" Property="Visibility"
                                Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12"/>
</Style>
```

Теперь можно использовать новое окно как обычно:

```
<code:WindowWithMessage x:Class="Namespace.MyMainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:code="clr-namespace:YourLibrary"
    Width="400" Height="600"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    MessageText="Test">
    <Grid Background="Blue">
        <!-- content -->
    </Grid>
</code:WindowWithMessage>
```

Comment: @Nodon: Закончил.

Comment: Жаль что я сходу это понять не могу, тк навыков недостаточно. Но за ответ спасибо, обязательно разберусь и поиграюсь с этим.

Comment: @Nodon: С UserControl'ами тоже хорошая идея. Они не заменяют окно, но позволяют собирать UI из кусочков. Они вам скорее всего больше пригодятся, чем техника написания своего окна.

Comment: Но UserControl'ы не позволяют так просто класть контент _внутрь_ себя. С окном такой трюк проходит без проблем.

Comment: Ну свои контролы уже имею опыт писать, давелось даже свою панель с 0 написать(ох сколько грабель собрал я). Я сейчас сделал шаблонное окно, в котором есть куча элементов, некоторые друг друга перекрывают даже. Видимость элементов привязана к свойствам шаблонного ViewModel

Answer (score 4):

В WPF отсутствует наследование отображения. Вместо этого можно использовать UserControl-ы.
пример:

```
<Window xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.MyUserControl" >
    <StackPanel>
        <local:MyUserControl />
        <Button Content="OK" Click="OkClickHandler" />
        <Button Content="Cancel" Click="CancelClickHandler" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: У меня и так сделано кучу контролов. Мне главное то, как они будут располагаться на экране. Это вот расположение всегда идентично, отличие только в том, что где-то есть доп кнопки или еще какие элементы

Answer (score 3):

Привет, да наследование UI в  WPF сделано так себе...
Что бы иметь возможность наследовать UI приходится писать код на С# а не на xaml
И так простой пример: 
Супер класс

```
public class BaseWindow : Window
{
    protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
    {
        created = false;
        var content = (IAddChild)newContent;
        // Создаем табличку для примера 
        var g = new Grid();
        var groupsColumns = new ColumnDefinition();
        var b = new Binding("GroupWidth");
        groupsColumns.SetBinding(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, b);
        g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(groupsColumns);
        g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto });
        g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star) });       
        content.AddChild(g);     
    }

    bool created; // пригодится в событии Loaded
}
```

После этого мы можем переопределить Window

```
<base:BaseWindow 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.MyUserControl" 
      xmlns:base="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.BaseWindow" 
       >
<StackPanel>
    <local:MyUserControl />
    <Button Content="OK" Click="OkClickHandler" />
    <Button Content="Cancel" Click="CancelClickHandler" />
</StackPanel>
</base:BaseWindow>
```